# Como puedo buscar un objeto en un arreglo (VsCode - Ts)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic, vscode

Buen día.
Actualmente en mi programa tengo un arreglo con 2 objetos de tipo Usuario.

```
[
    {
        "email": "smoreno055@gmail.com",
        "rol": "1"
    },
    {
        "email": "praus_d871e@xeoty.com",
        "rol": "2"
    }
]
```

Deseo consultar el usuario que esta ingresando, para establecer que rol tiene y poder hacer una redirección.

```
private redirectUser(isVerified: boolean,email :string): void {
console.log(this.Usuarios);
console.log(email);
const usuario=this.Usuarios.find(x => x.email = email);
if (isVerified) {
   console.log(usuario.rol);
   this.router.navigate(['admin']);
} else {
  this.router.navigate(['verify-email']);
}
```

}
}

¿Cuál es el problema?
Al momento de declarar la constante Usuario, esta esta asignando al arreglo el usuario con el que se esta iniciando.

```
const usuario=this.Usuarios.find(x => x.email = email);
```

Lo cual me deja como resultado en el arreglo:

```
[
    {
        "email": "praus_d871e@xeoty.com",
        "rol": "1"
    },
    {
        "email": "praus_d871e@xeoty.com",
        "rol": "2"
    }
]
```

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Te falta un par de `=`: `const usuario=this.Usuarios.find(x => x.email === email);`

Comment: Pablo, gracias por tu ayuda, pero sigue ocasionando que se cambie el arreglo.

Comment: @SebasMoreno Puedes actualizar tu código con la modificación?

Comment: Sebastian te recomiendo cambiar el find por el filter, ya que el filter te devolvera la coincidencia y no un arreglo, tambien como dice @legna actualiza tu codigo y agrega un "=" al comparativo

Answer (score 0):

Sebastian quizas tengas un problema con el correo que estas tratando de filtrar (puede que tenga algun espacio o algo asi, trata de hacer un console.log para que veas que esta revisando), por otra parte te recomiendo cambiar el "find" por "filter" de esta manera:

```js
const usuarios = [
    {
        "email": "smoreno055@gmail.com",
        "rol": "1"
    },
    {
        "email": "praus_d871e@xeoty.com",
        "rol": "2"
    } ]

console.log(usuarios)

const userFiltrado = usuarios.find(x=> x.email ==  "smoreno055@gmail.com" )

console.log("usuario filtrado ->",userFiltrado)
```